# ANDROID : How to register for connectivity change from an Service?

Tags: android, service, broadcast, connectivity

In my application I have a single service which does updates to all GUI elements. So I need to register my service to CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_ACTION. So that it can notify all activity to update GUI whenever it receives any connection updates as broadcast.

To achieve this I declared a public member class broadcast receiver in my service. Following are code snippets.

```
public class BkgService extends Service{

public class ConnectionUpdater extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {

            }
            else{
                cd.setIsOnline(true,context);
            }

            Intent intent1 = new Intent();
            intent1.setAction(ACTION_GUI_UPDATE);
            sendBroadcast(intent1);
        }

}
```

in my manifest file I declared like this

```
<service android:name=".BkgService" />

<receiver android:name="BkgService.ConnectionUpdater">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I am not getting any error for this. But I don't get any broadcast updates when I enable/disable the 3G data in virtual device. Please suggest what may be going wrong? Am I doing it in right way?

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
<receiver android:name=".BkgService$ConnectionUpdater">
```

You missed the `.` before `BkgService` and the inner class name should be separated from the main class with a `$` sign.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I made the necessary changes. I am getting the broadcast. But my program crashes immediately just after I receive the broadcast. This the error I am getting : 02-26 04:48:04.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver mt.android.app.BkgService$ConnectionUpdater: java.lang.InstantiationException: mt.android.app.BkgService$ConnectionUpdater

Comment: The reason for your exception might be that your inner class is not static, hence it takes a reference to the outer class when instantiated. Thus the Android Runtime cannot create an instance without passing a reference to the outer class. Try declaring your inner class as ``static``.